# Google Sign In returns error 12501 when authenticating on Google Pixel but works on other devices

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin, google-pixel

I have a problem getting a Google Sign in to work on a Google Pixel device using com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn. I can log in on other Android devices but when I try to log in on the Google Pixel device the sign in intent returns a 12501 status code as if the user had cancelled the sign in process.

I only get to the list of Google accounts and not to the permissions screen.

I have already set up credentials in the developer console. They already work for other devices.

My java code for signing in looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    ...


    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(GOOGLE_CALENDAR_SCOPE))
            .requestServerAuthCode(GOOGLE_CONSOLE_CLIENT_ID, true)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
}

...

public void loadGoogleCalendar() {
    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

    if(account != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "already signed in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        loadCalendarsForAccount(account);
    } else {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGNIN_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

I have tried signing in using a variety of devices and the error only seems to occur on Google Pixel.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Device           | Google Play      | Android     | Result            |
|                  | Services Version | Version     |                   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Huawei PRA-LX1   | 15.0.90          | 8.0.0 API26 | OK                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Samsung SM-G950F | 14.8.49          | 8.0.0 API26 | OK                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sony F5321       | 15.0.90          | 7.0 API24   | OK                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Google Pixel     | 15.0.90          | 8.1.0 API27 | 12501             |
|                  |                  |             | SIGN_IN_CANCELLED |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ONEPLUS A600     | 15.0.90          | 9 API28     | OK                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What can I do to resolve this bug?

Comment: Any news on this? I'm experiencing the same random behavior. Would gladly share experiences in order to get down to this.